# Como puedo crear un objeto de métodos de manera automática?

Tags: javascript, lógica

Hola amigos soy nuevo en la comunidad y estoy tratando de dar respuesta a algo que se me ha tornado complejo, ¿Cómo puedo crear un objeto que contenga dentro de si, uno o varios métodos?:

```
const columnas = {
uno: (item) => (
  <td>item.nombre</td>
),
dos: (item) => (
  <td>item.nombre</td>
),
tres: (item) => (
  <td>item.nombre</td>
)
```

Claro cada uno de estos metodos y sus nombres debe cambiar automáticamente  por decir un ejemplo tengo una tabla y tengo un objeto para poner el encabezado seria algo asi:

```
const header = [
{
  nombre: 'Productos',
  key: 'producto',
},
{
  nombre: 'Tienda Uno',
  key: 1,
},
{
  nombre: 'Tienda Dos',
  key: 2
},
{
  nombre: 'Tienda Tres',
  key: 3,
}]
```

Yo me lo imaginaba algo asi:

```
let arrayFunciones = []
Object.keys(header).forEach((key) => {
let value = header[key]
if (!isNaN(value.key)) {
  const numeroCadena = value.key.toString()
  const objeto = {
    [numeroCadena]: (item) => <td>{item}</td>,
  }
  console.log(objeto)
  arrayFunciones = [objeto, ...arrayFunciones]
}
```

})

Agradezco mucho su tiempo, y disculpen si no fui claro

Comment: Tal como lo tienes parece correcto excepto por lo que devuelve el método, debería ser una cadena, no? `item => (\`<td>${item.nombre}</td>\`)`.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando con react? Si es solo javascript la sintaxis `<td>item.nombre</td>` no es válida. Por otro lado, no entiendo exactamente que quieres hacer. ¿Por qué tener n funciones que hacen exactamente lo mismo en un objeto? ¡Don't repeat yourself!

Comment: Lo que sucede amigos es que estoy trabajando con tablas, y quiero poder manipular los valores de una columna en especifico, para eso tengo que nombrar el key, en los casos mencionados antes, si yo quiero poder usar la información que viene en dicha columna tengo que mencionar el key de la columna que deseo usar, 1: () => {}, pero la cantidad de columnas puede cambiar, y como la informacion que viene es un objeto con la data de las columnas, pues eso me lo ha vuelto complicado, gracias por comentar!

Comment: Creo que en el momento que dijiste que la cantidad de columnas de la tabla puede cambiar, ahi es donde se da el mal planteamiento, pues ten en cuenta que si vas a hacerlo de esa manera (sin una cantidad fija de columnas), entonces vas a tener que estar comprobando a cada rato cuales datos existen y cuales no, y que tu estructura de la tabla puede estar variando mucho dependiendo de lo que te llegue desde la BD, a mi parecer es mas sencillo que simplemente hagas un analisis de TODAS las columnas que pueedan llegar a aparecer en la tabla.

Comment: A continuacion desde el backend mandes un arreglo de informacion que SIEMPRE mande la informacion completa de las cabeceras de los datos (en un object junto con demas informacion), mientras que para el caso de los datos mantengas todas las propiedades (columnas) y aquellas propiedades que no contengan información simplemente las añadas como valores de un objeto pero vacias.

Comment: Ahora bien, esto puedes limitarlo mas según tus gustos, por ejemplo, si te parece que queda muy extenso simplemente quitas aquellas columnas que no quieras que aparezcan.

Comment: Estructura del objeto*.